# C# - Time calculation not working with TimeSpan.FromTicks DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am trying to calculate a video framerate in a program. To do this I take

```
DateTime.Now
```

at the beginning of a stream, and then again after every frame whilst also incrementing a framecounter.

Then I calculate the FPS like so:

```
int fps = (int)(frames / (TimeSpan.FromTicks(CurrentTime.Ticks).Seconds - TimeSpan.FromTicks(StartTime.Ticks).Seconds));
```

The problem is that I occassionally get a negative number out, meaning the start time must be later than the current time. How can this be the case? Does anyone know anough about these functions to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datetime functions are probably not precise enough for your needs, you may want to look into performance counters instead. I think the StopWatch class is what your looking for. System.Diagnostics.StopWatch. that is using the QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter functions for the timing.

Answer (score 6):

Seconds gives you the seconds part of the TimeSpan, not the total duration of the TimeSpan converted in seconds. This means that Seconds will never be greater than 60.

Use TotalSeconds instead

Comment: +1, you're right, but even so the current time could still go backwards because an administrator changed the time, or the system synchronized with a time server.  Better to use the StopWatch class, which in addition will use a high-resolution performance counter if available.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for such needs, It has much better precision